# Multiple tables with one calendar table for Power Bi DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have just created a calendar table in my model my power bi has multiple different excel spreadsheets each has their own date field is there a way to connect these all to a calendar table so when using a slicer you only need to reference the calendar table for which month or year you need to filter on?

also how would you fix this line of DAX if i did add a calendar table see how the bottom line is ref a date from the current file would that change when creating a date table?

```
   Monthly Total Actuals = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('YTD'[Amount]),
    FILTER('YTD','YTD'[Analysis Type] = "ACT"),
    FILTER('YTD', 'YTD'[Bill to Project Costing] = "Y"), 
    FILTER('YTD', 'YTD'[Month Billed].[MonthNo] = MONTH(TODAY()) -1 )
    )
```

thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried creating a relationship between the calender table and the others?

Comment: I have but then the formula above didnt work